# i was using the same method for pagination and search in rails . m struggling with product.rb (Dont know how to use two methods in one method )

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**product.rb**

Method for pagination:

```
def self.search(search, page)  
  paginate :per_page => 5, :page => page,
           :conditions => ['name like ?', "%#{search}%"],
           :order => 'id'
end
```

Here is the method for search:

```
def self.search(search) 
  if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
```

**product_controller**

```
@products = Product.search(params[:search],params[:page])
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag products_path, :method => 'get' do %>  
  <p>  
    <%= text_field_tag :search, nil, :placeholder => "Search items here" %>  
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>  
  </p>  
<% end %>

<%= will_paginate @products%>
```

Comment: Please reformat your code.

Comment: you're having two methods with the exact same name in/for your `product` model?

Comment: yes , one for the search and second one for the pagination a... throwing an error like "wrong  no of arguments( 2 for 1)"

Comment: i want a search tab in my products (which search the product by name ) view as well as it paginates